# Restore multiple SQL Server .bak Files

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a folder with multiple .bak files of sql server.

I want to restore them to sql server. How can i do a script so that all backuped files from that folder can be restored at once.

Answer (score 1):

```
RESTORE DATABASE [db1] FROM  DISK = N'C:\folder\db1.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'DB_Data' TO N'C:\folder\db2.mdf',  MOVE N'DB_log' TO N'C:\folder\db1.LDF',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [db2] FROM  DISK = N'C:\folder\db2.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'DB_Data' TO N'C:\folder\db2.mdf',  MOVE N'DB_Log' TO N'C:\folder\db2.LDF',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Try something like this.

Comment: I want multiple restore from a single script

Comment: @KishoreJangid: this **IS** a **SINGLE** script ..... but you **CANNOT** restore more than one `*.bak` file with a single `RESTORE DATABASE ....` command (if that's what you really mean....)

Comment: I dont know the database names when i execute the script. it should get all the database backup files from a folder and restore them

Comment: Note that there are cases where you can restore more than one .bak file with a single RESTORE DATABASE: if a single backup has been split into multiple .bak files, you can restore them with multiple DISK statements within a single RESTORE DATABASE.

It might seem unrelated to this question, but I ended up here when searching for just that. :)

For more info, see example here:
https://www.sqlshack.com/split-sql-database-backups-into-multiple-backup-files-using-ssms/

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess databases name is not written into .bak file. No idea how to retreive by script. You may use file name or any other temp name for restored databases and after restore rename it under SSMS.
2. Be aware that .bak files may contain DIFF backups. In case of DIFF backup, it won't work just like that - one by one.
3. If folder contains FULL BACKUP and TRANSACTION LOG backups it's always the best idea to start restoring database using backup history in SSMS.

Let's talk about restoring multiple databases from multiple BAK files.
I think GAWK may help. It's not the MS way, but may be the fastest way.

Do you know GAWK?

Let you build input file with file names:

```
dir *.bak > input.txt
```

Write GAWK program into file program.gawk.txt:

```
BEGIN {
printf "-- My auto-generated script \n"
}
{
printf "RESTORE DATABASE [substr($1,1,length($1)-4)] FROM DISK = N'$1 \n'"
printf "GO \n\n"
}
END {
printf "-- End of script"
}
```

Experiment with substr to generate temp name for restored database based on BAK file name. Not sure if substr expression is all right - please check yourself.

- $1 will be changed to file name from input.txt
- substr($1,1,length($1)-4) is for cutting ".BAK" from filename

Build output script by:

```
gawk --file=program.gawk.txt input.txt > my_script.sql
```

..and review it.

Maybe it's possible to do this powershell-way. Don't know.

Download GAWK from: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm