# Trying to merge rows into one row with certain conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Given 2 or more rows that are selected to merge, one of them is identified as being the template row. The other rows should merge their data into any null value columns that the template has.

Example data:

```
Id  Name     Address          City          State   Active  Email             Date
1   Acme1    NULL             NULL          NULL    NULL    blah@yada.com     3/1/2011
2   Acme1    1234 Abc Rd      Springfield   OR      0       blah@gmail.com    1/12/2012
3   Acme2    NULL             NULL          NULL    1       blah@yahoo.com    4/19/2012
```

Say that a user has chosen row with Id 1 as the template row, and rows with Ids 2 and 3 are to be merged into row 1 and then deleted. Any null value columns in row Id 1 should be filled with (if one exists) the most recent (see Date column) non-null value, and non-null values already present in row Id 1 are to be left as is. The result of this query on the above data should be exactly this:

```
Id  Name     Address          City          State   Active  Email             Date
1   Acme1    1234 Abc Road    Springfield   OR      1       blah@yada.com     3/1/2011
```

Notice that the Active value is 1, and not 0 because row Id 3 had the most recent date.

**P.S. Also, is there any way possible to do this without explicitly defining/knowing beforehand what all the column names are? The actual table I'm working with has a ton of columns, with new ones being added all the time. Is there a way to look up all the column names in the table, and then use that subquery or temptable to do the job?**

Comment: Should the email then also be blah@yahoo.com, or is Acme2 considered out of bounds for the merge?

Comment: How you identify the group of data ? I guess you want to merge doublets of data. So how you identify a group of data in thousand or more of records in your table? If you know that then you can go ofc write a stored procedure doing this. If necessary I can write a sample SP as answer then

Comment: Hi Russell Fox, no, the email should remain blah@yada.com because it was already present in row Id 1. Only null value columns in Id 1 should be modified at all.

Comment: Hi YvesR, the group of data is selected by a User via a datagrid where the user selects rows by checkbox. The row Ids are passed into an SP via a parameter: a comma-delimited varchar of Ids by which I use an iteration function to parse the Ids, then use them to pull the data from their respective table in order to return the data you see above. The Id of the template row is also passed as a parameter to the SP so that I know which row is the base row to merge the others into.

Comment: PS. When the user selects rows in the UI, and then clicks a "merge" button, a popup with all selected rows is shown, within which the user then clicks a radio button on one of the rows to indicate the row they wish to merge the others into.

Answer (score 2):

You might do it by ordering rows first by template flag, then by date desc. Template row should always be the last one. Each row is assigned a number in that order. Using max() we are finding fist occupied cell (in descending order of numbers). Then we select columns from rows matching those maximums.

```
; with rows as (
    select test.*,
  -- Template row must be last - how do you decide which one is template row?
  -- In this case template row is the one with id = 1
    row_number() over (order by case when id = 1 then 1 else 0 end,
                       date) rn
    from test
  -- Your list of rows to merge goes here
  -- where id in ( ... )
),
-- Finding first occupied row per column
positions as (
  select
    max (case when Name is not null then rn else 0 end) NamePosition,
    max (case when Address is not null then rn else 0 end) AddressPosition,
    max (case when City is not null then rn else 0 end) CityPosition,
    max (case when State is not null then rn else 0 end) StatePosition,
    max (case when Active is not null then rn else 0 end) ActivePosition,
    max (case when Email is not null then rn else 0 end) EmailPosition,
    max (case when Date is not null then rn else 0 end) DatePosition
  from rows
)
-- Finally join this columns in one row
select 
  (select Name from rows cross join Positions where rn = NamePosition) name,
  (select Address from rows cross join Positions where rn = AddressPosition) Address,
  (select City from rows cross join Positions where rn = CityPosition) City,
  (select State from rows cross join Positions where rn = StatePosition) State,
  (select Active from rows cross join Positions where rn = ActivePosition) Active,
  (select Email from rows cross join Positions where rn = EmailPosition) Email,
  (select Date from rows cross join Positions where rn = DatePosition) Date
from test
-- Any id will suffice, or even DISTINCT
where id = 1
```

[You might check it at Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3e753/8).

EDIT:

Cross joins in last section might actually be inner joins on rows.rn = xxxPosition. It works this way, but change to inner join would be an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so complicated.

At first..
`DECLARE @templateID INT = 1`
..so you can remember which row is treated as template..

Now find latest `NOT NULL` values (exclude template row). The easiest way is to use `TOP 1` subqueries for each column:

```
SELECT
(SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM DataTab WHERE Name IS NOT NULL AND NOT ID = @templateID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS LatestName,
(SELECT TOP 1 Address FROM DataTab WHERE Address IS NOT NULL AND NOT ID = @templateID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS AddressName
-- add more columns here
```

Wrap above into CTE (Common Table Expression) so you have nice input for your `UDPATE`..

```
WITH Latest_CTE (CTE_LatestName, CTE_AddressName) -- add more columns here; I like CTE prefix to distinguish source columns from target columns..
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM DataTab WHERE Name IS NOT NULL AND NOT ID = @templateID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS LatestName,
    (SELECT TOP 1 Address FROM DataTab WHERE Address IS NOT NULL AND NOT ID = @templateID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS AddressName
    -- add more columns here
)
UPDATE
<update statement here (below)>
```

Now, do smart `UPDATE` of your template row using `ISNULL` - it will act as conditional update - update only if target column is null

```
WITH
<common expression statement here (above)>
UPDATE DataTab
SET 
Name = ISNULL(Name, CTE_LatestName), -- if Name is null then set Name to CTE_LatestName else keep Name as Name
Address = ISNULL(Address, CTE_LatestAddress)
-- add more columns here..
WHERE ID = @templateID
```

And the last task is delete rows other then template row..

```
DELETE FROM DataTab WHERE NOT ID = @templateID
```

Clear?

Comment: I think that makes sense, and I will give it a go, but is there any way possible to do it without explicitly defining/knowing beforehand what all the column names are? The actual table I'm working with has a ton of columns, with new ones being added all the time. Is there a way to look up all the column names in the table, and then use that subquery or temptable to do the job?

Comment: Use sys.columns catalog view to get all columns names from your table (exclude ID column from this set). Now 1) use dynamic SQL - it's headache I think and performance goes down. Or 2) output column names from sys.columns into text file, then use AWK/GAWK program to generate target script using "template". Save your GAWK-program for future use (rebuild/refresh your SQL script).

Comment: See my GAWK-solutions on another SQL-problem to get the idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10122169/1280816 I'm sure that you have a lot of columns but number of columns in final product will be static. It's better to do external SQL script generator than to loose performance on every query execution and loop thru column names.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic columns, you need to write a solution using dynamic SQL.

You can query sys.columns and sys.tables to get the list of columns you need, then you want to loop backwards once for each null column finding the first non-null row for that column and updating your output row for that column. Once you get to 0 in the loop you have a complete row which you can then display to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; that sounds like exactly what I need to do, but I am having a difficult time having a concrete coneptualization without seeing some code. If it's not to much trouble, could you please throw some code in here so I can better understand? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I should pay attention to posting dates. In any case, here's a solution using dynamic SQL to build out an update statement. It should give you something to build from, anyway.

There's some extra code in there to validate the results along the way, but I tried to comment in a way that made that non-vital code apparent.

```
CREATE TABLE 
dbo.Dummy 
    (
    [ID] int ,
    [Name] varchar(30),
    [Address] varchar(40) null,
    [City]  varchar(30) NULL,
    [State] varchar(2) NULL,
    [Active] tinyint NULL,
    [Email] varchar(30) NULL,
    [Date] date NULL
    );
--
INSERT dbo.Dummy
VALUES
(
    1, 'Acme1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah@yada.com', '3/1/2011'
)
,
(
    2, 'Acme1', '1234 Abc Rd', 'Springfield', 'OR', 0, 'blah@gmail.com', '1/12/2012'
)
,
(
    3, 'Acme2', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 'blah@yahoo.com', '4/19/2012'
);
DECLARE 
    @TableName nvarchar(128) = 'Dummy',
    @TemplateID int = 1,
    @SetStmtList nvarchar(max) = '',
    @LoopCounter int = 0,
    @ColumnCount int = 0,
    @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''
    ;
--
--Create a table to hold the column names
DECLARE     
    @ColumnList table 
        (
        ColumnID tinyint IDENTITY,
        ColumnName nvarchar(128)
        );
--
--Get the column names
INSERT @ColumnList
(
    ColumnName
)
    SELECT
        c.name
    FROM
        sys.columns AS c
        JOIN
        sys.tables AS t
            ON
                t.object_id = c.object_id
    WHERE
        t.name = @TableName;
--
--Create loop boundaries to build out the SQL statement
SELECT
    @ColumnCount = MAX( l.ColumnID ),
    @LoopCounter = MIN (l.ColumnID )
FROM
    @ColumnList AS l;
--
--Loop over the column names
WHILE @LoopCounter <= @ColumnCount
BEGIN
    --Dynamically construct SET statements for each column except ID (See the WHERE clause)
    SELECT 
        @SetStmtList = @SetStmtList + ',' + l.ColumnName + ' =COALESCE(' + l.ColumnName + ', (SELECT TOP 1 ' + l.ColumnName + ' FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + l.ColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL AND ID <> ' + CAST(@TemplateID AS NVARCHAR(MAX )) + ' ORDER BY Date DESC)) '
    FROM 
        @ColumnList AS l
    WHERE 
        l.ColumnID = @LoopCounter
        AND
        l.ColumnName <> 'ID';
--
    SELECT
        @LoopCounter = @LoopCounter + 1;
--
END;

--TESTING - Validate the initial table values
SELECT * FROM dbo.Dummy ;
--
--Get rid of the leading common in the SetStmtList
SET @SetStmtList = SUBSTRING( @SetStmtList, 2, LEN( @SetStmtList ) - 1 );
--Build out the rest of the UPDATE statement
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName  + ' SET ' + @SetStmtList + ' WHERE ID = ' + CAST(@TemplateID AS NVARCHAR(MAX ))
--Then execute the update
EXEC sys.sp_executesql
    @SQL;
--
--TESTING - Validate the updated table values
SELECT * FROM dbo.Dummy ;
--
--Build out the DELETE statement
SET @SQL = 'DELETE FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ID <> ' + CAST(@TemplateID AS NVARCHAR(MAX ))
--Execute the DELETE
EXEC sys.sp_executesql
    @SQL;
--
--TESTING - Validate the final table values
SELECT * FROM dbo.Dummy; 
--
DROP TABLE dbo.Dummy;
```